# Playing a scale with a flat 10 across multiple octaves

Tags: scales, modes, intervals

Let's say I'm playing a keyboard solo and I'm using a C major scale with a flat 10.

So I play an E in the first octave and an E flat in the second octave, but then I get very, showy prog-rocky and I go up to a third octave.

Is the E natural or flat? Is the flat ten sticky across all higher octaves? Does it revert to just being a third across the higher octaves? Does it flip back and forth between being a third and a tenth?

I'm wondering both if there's a "correct" answer and what you would expect an algorithm to do if it was playing a scale up five octaves.

Comment: Why not both? Also, why not call it a #9?

Answer (score 7):

Dealer's choice. Altering a note within a scale can be done at any time, presuming the underlying harmony is the same. Thus, in the third octave one could play the third, the flat third (tenth), or even both. One could even think of the b10 as a #9 and use it as a replacement for the 2.

In the context of this topic, scales are a means of traveling between harmony notes, so in that sense the entire chromatic scale is always available. One just has to have the ear for how to make the passing tones (scale) work.

Answer (score 3):

There is not a "correct" answer.

It's definitely not "sticky".

Even in classical style you can have what is called a *cross relationship* between differing chromatic tones of a single pitch letter in a single melodic line or between lines in counterpoint. For example, a `G♯` against a `G♮` in the key of `A` minor. Those cross relationships usually follow harmonic conventions, but the details aren't necessary to answer your question.

In modern harmonic styles (prog rock being an example) there is much less sense of a convention to follow, and the treatment is much freer, a personal choice.

It seems worth mentioning that there is a certain *blusey* sound where a major triad base chord, like a `C7` chord uses a *major third* in the chord, but in a melodic line harmonized by such chords, the line will use a *flat third*, or it could be enharmonically spelled like a *sharp ninth*, and that cross relationship is part of the *blusey* sound. That chromatic tone isn't necessarily "sticky", but there is a tendancy for it to be in a higher range, in an octave above the chord.

Comment: Important mention of cross relations.

Answer (score 2):

First you talk about a scale, then a solo. The two are only linked by the actual notes contained within - they're not related in any other way. So a scale will use notes from a key in ascending and descending order - that's what scales are, whereas solos will use some, any or all the notes from that key/scale in whatever order fits the underlying harmony.

You are in fact mixing the major and minor scale notes - C major and C **melodic** minor (ascending, or jazz) differ only by that third - M3 in major, m3 in minor. It's commonplace to play m3 over major chords - blues and jazz do it all the time!

So, it's basically whatever you want. You could use either in any octave, you just decided to do what you did. When playing higher, it might even sound good on guitar (there's no clue as to what instrument) to play m3 and bend up to M3 at appropriate places.